# Shortest path in a grid

Tags: combinatorics

I have this question and I don't know exactly how to solve it; the question is: 
Give the number of shortest paths from (-2,5) to (2,-1)?
please, I need a help...

Comment: Draw the grid, and start by counting the number of shortest paths from $(-2, 5)$ to some closer points, like $(-1, 5)$, $(-2, 4)$ and $(-1, 4)$. Then work your way systematically towards $(2, -1)$.

Comment: I mean there is no specific rule to solve this question?

Comment: @A.QE There is, but I personally believe that if you discover it on your own, you will have learned a lot more and end up a better mathematician than if someone on the internet just tells you.

Comment: yes I know, but I want to make sure of my answer